# File "solution.py", line 36 return B1 SyntaxError: 'return' outside function. Genuine

Tags: python-2.7, indentation

```
class Solution:
    # @param a : list of list of integers
    # @return a list of list of integers
    def diagonal(self, a):
        mylen = len(a)
        t_v = 2*len(a)
        ret_val = 2*mylen-1
        B1=[[0 for x in range(y)] for y in range(1,t_v/2+1)]
        B2=[[0 for x in range(y)] for y in range(t_v/2-1,0,-1)]

        for i in range((t_v/2)-1):
            B1.append(B2)

        for i in range(t_v/2):
            c=i
            vark=0
            for j in range(i+1):
                B1[i][vark] = a[j][c]
                vark += 1
                c -= 1

        myindex=t_v/2
        someVal=1

        for i in range(t_v/2-1, 0, -1):
            c=len(a)-1
            vark=0
            mytrack=someVal
            for j in range(i):
                B1[myindex][j] = a[mytrack][c]
                mytrack += 1
                c -= 1
            myindex +=1
            someVal += 1

        return B1
```

Comment: i fixed the indentation of your code. did that change the indentation of the last line? because the code as it is is valid python. (i can not reproduce your error).

Comment: Thankyou hiro, I also got a solution. It was a mix of spaces and tabs. Just copied the code in sublime and then made strict indentation with tabs. That's all. This was the fix.